# Format file contents don't typeset

Tags: tex-core, format-files

I created the following myformat.tex file, and converted it to a .fmt file using `tex -ini myformat`.

```
\input plain
Friend, Romans, countrymen,
\dump
```

I then wrote the following manuscript, mymanuscript.tex, and compiled it with the above format using `tex \&myformat mymanuscript`.

```
Lend me your ears!%
\bye
```

I expected the resulting pdf to consist of the two lines

```
Friends, Romans, countrymen,
Lend me your ears!
```

Instead, it consisted of the single line

```
Lend me your ears!
```

Why?

Comment: It does typeset.  However, it does so during the INITEX run.  If I dump your format I get a `myformat.dvi` with these contents.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Why doesn't it do so during the non-INITEX run?

Comment: @HenriMenke: What do you mean by "dump your format"? How do you do this?

Comment: Dumping (creating) a format file only saves the "state" of TeX w.r.t. parameters (like `\hsize`), registers, macro definitions, etc. AFAIK it does not save the contents of the main vertical list or whatever. (And in any case, as Henri explains, even if it were going to do that, the main vertical list would have been typeset and gone before dumping, so probably the question does not even arise.)

Comment: you can see `latex.ltx` or [source2e.pdf](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base) for the definition of `\@begindvi`

Comment: @touhami: I'm sorry but I don't see what this has to do with my question. Could you please explain?

Comment: this does not answer the why in your question, but how to automatically add something at the very beginning of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expected the resulting pdf to consist of the two lines [...]
>   Instead, it consisted of the single line [...]
>   Why?

Because it has already been output during the INITEX run and is therefore gone.

I don't know whether you can “save” the vertical list during INITEX for later reuse.  In your situation that is not the case.  You would need extra work.  Below I tell why.

After inputing `plain.tex` the output routine is set to `\plainoutput`.  That means once INITEX encounters `\end` (or `\dump`) the output routine will run and shipout the vertical list constructed from your input.  Because `\shipout` sets the page (by default `\box255`) to void after shipping it out, there is no way to recover stuff typeset during INITEX in a normal TeX run.

Comment: You wrote: "After inputing plain.tex the output routine is set to `\plainoutput`. That means..." But the same problem comes up even when I don't input plain.tex.

Comment: @EvanAad Of course, you somehow have to provide an own output routine which saves the typeset content to be retrieved in the normal TeX run.  You *have* to write that yourself, there is no built-in magic for that.